# Increase speed of python with Flask-SQLAlchemy when getting data (to json) fields from db

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have 1000 pages and 10 000 tags. Sample structure of the db:

```
tags = db.Table('tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('page_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('page.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Page(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags, lazy='subquery',
        backref=db.backref('pages', lazy=True))
    page_name = db.Column(db.String(20))

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_name = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

I need to get a json with fields like **page_name** and then list of **tag_name** under each **page_name**. Only the mentioned fields, nothing else to be included.

Now I am simply looping like this:

```
pages_list = []
pages = Page.query.all()
for page in pages:
    page_temp = {}
    page_name = page.page_name
    page_temp['page_name'] = page_name

    tags = []
    for tag in page.tags:
        tags.append(tag.tag_name)
    
    page_temp['tags'] = tags
    pages_list.append(page_temp)
#then return pages_list as json
```

However, it is giving me undesired load speed. Is there a way to improve the speed here and get the desired json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is not need to do `pages = Page.query.all()`, because `Page.query` should be an iterator.
It can improve your query load time.

Secondly, by using `lazy='subquery'` you have additional query to fetch `tags` for each `page`. You can force to have one query selecting all `pages` with `tags` by setting `lazy=joined` (docs for it: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html#joined-eager-loading). So when you execute `page.tags` no additional implicit query would be hitted (you would have 1 query instead of `<number of pages> + 1` queries). The question is whether you always want to fetch `tags` when you fetching `page`? If not, you can use `joinedload` at query side:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload

pages_list = []
pages = Page.query.options(joinedload(Page.tags))
for page in pages:
    page_temp = {}
    page_name = page.page_name
    page_temp['page_name'] = page_name

    tags = []
    for tag in page.tags:
        tags.append(tag.tag_name)
    
    page_temp['tags'] = tags
    pages_list.append(page_temp)
#then return pages_list as json
```

Rendering a structure of 10k pages with a lot of tags associated would always take some time. Can you consider a pagination of this data? Or you have to fetch it in one request?